# Multiple record types and how to split them amongst tables

Tags: sql

I'm working on a database structure and trying to imagine the best way to split up a host of related records into tables. Records all have the same base type they inherit from, but each then expands on it for their particular use.

These 4 properties are present for every type.

```
id, name, groupid, userid
```

Here are the types that expand off those 4 properties.

```
"Static": value
"Increment": currentValue, maxValue, overMaxAllowed, underNegativeAllowed
"Target": targetValue, result, lastResult
```

What I tried initially was to create a "records" table with the 4 base properties in it. I then created 3 other tables named "records_static/increment/target", each with their specific properties as columns. I then forged relationships between a "rowID" column in each of these secondary tables with the main table's "id".

Populating the tables with dummy data, I am now having some major problems attempting to extract the data with a query. The only parameter is the userid, beyond that what I need is a table with all of the columns and data associated with the userid.

I am unsure if I should abandon that table design, or if I just am going about the query incorrectly.

I hope I explained that well enough, please let me know if you need additional detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the design as simple as possible.

First I'd try a single table that contains all attributes that might apply to a record.  Irrelevant attributes can be `null`.  You can enforce `null` values for a specific type with a `check` constraint.

If that doesn't work out, you can create three tables for each record type, without a common table.

If that doesn't work out, you can create a base table with 1:1 extension tables.  Be aware that querying that is much harder, requiring `join` for every operation:

```
select  *
from    fruit f
left join
        apple a
on      a.fruit_id = f.id
left join
        pear p
on      p.fruit_id = f.id
left join
        ...
```

The more complex the design, the more room for an inconsistent database state.  The second option you could have a pear and an apple with the same id.  In the third option you can have missing rows in either the base or the extension table.  Or the tables can contradict each other, for example a base row saying "pear" with an extension row in the `Apple` table.  I fully trust end users to find a way to get that into your database :)

Throw out the complex design and start with the simplest one.  Your first attempt was not a failure: you now know the cost of adding relations between tables.  Which can look deceptively trivial (or even "right") at design time.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll give it a whirl. Good advice. 
I think I would tend to shy away from the first option since more record types could be introduced in the future and I don't want to end up with a super wide table. The second option may be more suited for my needs, but I would love to make the third option work.

Comment: I am so dumb. The problem was I was using "join" and not "left join". I didn't realize or forgot that "join" means "inner join." Your example of how to join the extension tables showed me the error of my ways. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical "object-oriented to relational" mapping problem. You can find books about this. Also a lot of google hits like

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-mapping-to-rdb/

The easiest for you to implement is to have one table containing all columns necessary to store all your types. Make sure you define them as nullable. Only the common columns can be not null if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the link.
Part of the issue is I wasn't sure how to structure a google search for this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just because object share some of the same properties does not mean you need to have one table for both objects.  That leads to unnecessary right outer joins that have a 1 to 1 relationship which is not what I think of as good database design.

but...

If you want to continue in your fashion I think all you need is a primary key in the table with common columns "id, name, groupid, userid" (I assume ID) then that would be the foreign key to your table with currentValue, maxValue, overMaxAllowed, underNegativeAllowed

Comment: I currently have a id->rowid relationship between the tables. Querying it seems to be difficult though.